# python's tkinter button color change is not getting updated

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a small program in which when a button is clicked the color of a label changes to green ( by default it was red ) and after sometime it reverts back to red. using time.sleep() doesn't work.

```
The code that I have already tried is:
    def change():
        label1.configure( bg ='green')
        #problem comes here ...
        label1.configure ( bg ='red')

    # label1 is defined here..........

    change()  #doesn't work......
```

How does the above work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you aren't calling [update()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) or `update_idletasks()` inside `change()`, so Tkinter never gets a chance to redraw the label with the different color before it gets changed back.

As patthoyts mentions in the comments, a much better way to do this sort of thing is to use the [after()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method, which lets you register a callback function that will be called after a given number of milliseconds.

Comment: Don't call `update`. Instead, use `after` to schedule an action to occur at a later time.

Comment: Thanks, @patthoyts. I haven't used Tkinter much (I mostly use GTK2+ for GUI work), so I'm not familiar with all of Tkinter's features.